# array values not same after initializing

Tags: c

I have written a piece of code in C language in which I am initializing an array with random numbers/characters. But when I print the array values after initializing it, I see that value on every index is equal to last assigned value (value of last index). Kindly tell what is the problem in my code?

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main () {

    char *save[3][3] = { {" "," "," "}, {" "," "," "}, {" "," "," "} };
    char x[2] = {'\0', '\0'};
    int i, j, b;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Assigned Values (initializing):\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
            b = rand()%10;
            x[0] = b+'0';
            save[i][j] = x;
            printf("%s ",save[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nValues after initializing:\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
            printf("%s ",save[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Assigned Values (initializing):
1 5 9 8 5 7 5 4 1

Values after initializing:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Do not write save[i][j] = x. It assigns the same pointer to all element of the array. Use strcpy() to copy values.

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti, and than invoke undefined behavior because all the pointers in `save` point to static storage.

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti Using `strcpy()` doesn't seem good choice here because modifying string literals will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @StoryTeller No, they don't point to static storage, they point to a local variable.  Even if they did, it wouldn't be undefined behavior because the memory is pointed to is still in scope.

Comment: @dbush Did you read what GiacomoDegliEsposti wrote? String literals are stored in static storage and elements of `save` are initiaized to them. If you modify string literals via `strcpy()`, it means you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @MikeCAT you're right, I missed that.  The elements of the matrix point to string literals, so they can't be modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You initialized all elements of elements of the array `save` to the same pointer, so what you can see using any of them will be same.

In this case, I suggest you should store the data directly in `save` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main (void) {

    char save[3][3][2] = { {" "," "," "}, {" "," "," "}, {" "," "," "} };
    int i, j, b;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Assigned Values (initializing):\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
            b = rand()%10;
            save[i][j][0] = b+'0';
            printf("%s ",save[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nValues after initializing:\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
            printf("%s ",save[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked! But I did not understand what you have done. You have used 3D array which means there will be `3x3x2 = 18` elements but in result 9 values are printed, so please explain how is this working?

Comment: @Agha There are `3x3=9` elements of type `char[2]` and they are printed. Though this is not the case here, please note that having *n* elements doesn't always mean that *n* values are printed. For example, you can print only first 10 elements of 1000-element array.